# Not being able to launch jupyter notebook in virtual conda environment in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to use jupyter notebook in a virtual conda environment in Ubuntu on a Windows 10 machine. I created a virtual conda environment and installed jupyter notebook in there, but when I try to open the jupyter notebook it shows this "The system cannot find the file specified.". I don't know what is happening. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: This looks like Powershell. Are you really using Ubuntu, or WSL?

Comment: Please provide the information in that image as text.

Comment: @darthbith I am pretty sure it is Ubuntu 18.04.